# How to fix Optional chaining Error on React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, web-applications, jsx

I am currently learning react redux and building an app at the same time. I used optional chaining for my user authentication. But i get this error message.

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

|       columnNumber: 11
|     }

> }, user?.displayName), /*#**PURE***/React.createElement("h3", {
> |     className: "headerOption__title",
> |     __self: this,

I have watched more that 10 video on youtube, but everyone seem to only explain what optional chaining is which i already know. But I want know how why its not working on my react app and how to fix it. Please help me with this problem, thanks.
here is how the React jsx code looks like

```
<Avatar className="headerOption__icon">
      {/* {user? user.displayName[0] : "" } */}
      {user?.displayName}
      </Avatar>
```

the ternary operator seem to work, but not the way i want. I want more like an if statement that doesn't use an else statement.

Comment: Can you show your setup please, webpack babel etc.. ? it will help to add optional chaining

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible you are using older version of React as It is working in my new versions but not in old one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

did you tried conditional rendering?

```
<Avatar className="headerOption__icon">
      {user && user.displayName[0]}

      </Avatar>
```